# How to reorder row in SELECT query in MYSQL?

Tags: mysql

A categories table which contains  `id`, `category_name`,`category_type` etc.

I am getting all the records with `SELECT` query.

suppose I have a `category name` `Shared article` and I want to get it first position in my records.

of course I am using simple query

```
 SELECT `category_name`,`category_type`,`categories`.`id`,
 count(`user_bookmarks`.`id`) as counter FROM `categories`
 LEFT JOIN `user_bookmarks` 
 ON `categories`.`id`=`user_bookmarks`.`category_id`
 WHERE `categories`.`user_id`=39 GROUP By `categories`.`category_name`
```

but I don't know how achieve my task?

Is it possible with `MySQL`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can do as

```
order by 
`categories`.`category_name` = 'Shared article' desc
```

Comment: Note that you have a group by clause so it will always have one record per group, however you may provide some sample data and expected result out of those sample data.

Comment: I am getting that category at first position but first position value replace with last position

Comment: Ah i see you need to add another order as `order by 
categories.category_name = 'Shared article' desc,categories.category_name`